# Anyone know of a TCP-based tunnel protocol linux will support?

Tags: tcp, tunneling

I have a lossy (1%) 10gig link between geographic locations which supports legacy systems that have non-tuneable TCP stacks.  They have horrible throughput across the link because their TCP stacks equate the loss with congestion, and dramatically reduce the window size.  Modern systems, set to use BBR congestion control, and with appropriately sized buffers, achieve 7+ Gbps across the same link.

My question is, does anyone know of a TCP-based bridging or tunneling protocol linux supports?  I can't use the typical UDP-based options (vxlan, geneve, gre), or IP protocol options (ipsec), because I've yet to find one that can be tuned to have that same level of performance, either due to design, or when faced with this 1% loss issue.  I want to configure a bridge or tunnel between the sites, using modern systems that support BBR and tuning, so they hide the loss from the legacy systems talking across them.

Only option I've found so far has been openvpn set to TCP mode and with encryption disabled, but it didn't have the throughput.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting. If the problem is that the TCP stack of your systems cannot deal with the loss, then setting up a tunnel using this TCP stack will not improve anything - because the bad performance of outer TCP connection will propagate into the tunnel. Using a UDP or similar based tunnel and then use the systems TCP stack inside it will also not help - because the tunnel simply propagates the properties of the link, i.e. including the loss. You would need to completely bypass the systems TCP stack instead, i.e. use some user space implementation in your application.

Comment: Having a pair of client/server proxies as tunnel endpoint (on tcp ports) on each side of the link would avoid the poor tcp stacks to notice anything. I'd say layer 4 or layer 7 tunnels. simplest tool: socat. or nginx, haproxy ... for one side at least. PLUS the OS without suboptimal IP stack that goes along.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the issue is that the devices in each location that want to talk to each other have inaccessible TCP stacks, reliant on out of date parameters and ancient congestion control algorithms.  I can't fix them, and I can't fix the lossy circuit.

However, if the ~1% lossy network between them is replaced by linux systems using a tcp-based tunnel, the tunnel endpoints will experience, mitigate, and hide the loss.  With tuning and BBR as the congestion control algorithm, they could present what appears to be a multi-gig loss-free connection.

Comment: Thanks @A.B. I'd glanced at socat but came away thinking it would not work, perhaps because it can't just bind to an interface and forward all TCP, but I'll re-check.  I've used haproxy before, but have not visited it for this issue; I'll see if there's a scenario I can come up with that it could help.

Comment: well with some elbow grease, at least 2 of the 3 tools mentioned can with Linux: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.rst

Comment: @ColoHost: A reliable tunnel over a lossy transport will substitute the packet loss with packet delay since it would need to detect the loss and retransmit the lost packets. I doubt that your old TCP stack can better deal with this.  You might see effects similar to [Bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm really talking about a proxy. Using a proxy lets the proxy (and only the proxy) deal with packet loss. OP told it could then be able to reach "7+ Gbps" with adequate network stack. The intent is not to tunnel TCP inside TCP. It's to have the proxy to be terminator of the IP traffic of the old systems.

Comment: @A.B. From my understanding the OP is asking about tunneling/bridging, i.e. still using the systems TCP stack but on top of a less lossy (tunneled) connectivity.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes. But I'm saying: frame challenge.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Also, the same way proxy ARP + a router at layer 3 can (imperfectly) mimick a bridge, transparent proxy at layer 4 (tcp) can (imperfectly) mimick a router: if the pair of proxy-like systems are in the path and implement transparent proxy features, this could require no or less change in the old systems: they would think their traffic was routed as usual, while they are actually proxified (where an ack is answered locally, the tcp window adjusted as needed depending on possible traffic etc.).

Comment: @A.B: You are right regarding the conceptional possibilities of such transparent proxies. But these cannot use the same old TCP stack as the original system because otherwise they run into the same problems. So they either need to run their own user space TCP stack or need to run on a separate system/VM with a better TCP stack.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I agree (with all you told btw). That's why I wrote "PLUS the OS without suboptimal IP stack that goes along." That meant a newer OS is needed to run the proxy (and I gave Linux as an example, to get the transparent proxy feature).

Comment: A reliable tunnel over lossy transport will be fine.  The sending and receiving systems, even if latency were to go up by 10%, would still ultimately open their tcp window enough to achieve multi-gig throughput, because they use ancient congestion control based mostly on loss.  Anything but loss will help them.  With the tunnel endpoints having 75% of the 10gig link capacity between them, we'd be fine.  You are correct that I'm talking about these systems continuing to use their tcp stack.

I unfortunately cannot use a proxy; these old systems don't have that functionality.